# Highcharts legend hover for bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to display map, line, and bar graphs on my site. In the line chart, when I hover over the legends, the corresponding line highlights. I want to do the same thing for my bar chart, so that when I hover over the legend the bar highlights the same way that it highlights when I hover over the bar itself. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is defining `hover` function for each of your `legend-item` and inside of this function, toggle `.setState('hover')` for all points of the relevant serie. like the following :

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Column chart with negative values'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
    }]
});



$('.highcharts-legend-item').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).hover(function() {
        $.each(chart.series[index].points, function(idx, elem)
        {
        elem.setState('hover');
        });
    },function() {
        $.each(chart.series[index].points, function(idx, elem)
        {
        elem.setState();
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```